# cs50 - pset7 - movies - 10.sql failed check50 test

Tags: sql, sqlite, cs50

I'm currently working on 10.sql which asked me to find all people who directed a movie that received a rating of at least 9.0

Here's the schema:

CREATE TABLE movies (

```
                id INTEGER,
                title TEXT NOT NULL,
                year NUMERIC,
                PRIMARY KEY(id)
            );
```

CREATE TABLE stars (

```
            movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
            FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
        );
```

CREATE TABLE directors (

```
            movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
            FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
        );
```

CREATE TABLE ratings (

```
            movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            rating REAL NOT NULL,
            votes INTEGER NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
        );
```

CREATE TABLE people (

```
            id INTEGER,
            name TEXT NOT NULL,
            birth NUMERIC,
            PRIMARY KEY(id)
        );
```

Here's the code I wrote:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people
JOIN directors ON directors.person_id = people.id
JOIN movies ON movies.id  = directors.person_id
JOIN ratings ON ratings.movie_id = movies.id
WHERE ratings.rating >= 9.0;
```

When I worked on sqlite3, it returned me a list of names. But it failed the check50 test with error message of 'Query did not return results'. I couldn't figure out why. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Many thanks

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to join on `movies`? Try:

```
SELECT
    name 
FROM
    people 
    JOIN directors ON people.id = directors.person_id 
    JOIN ratings ON directors.movie_id = ratings.movie_id 
WHERE
    ratings.rating >= 9.0
```

Comment: Thanks!It works! I was using movies to link between directors and ratings, forgot directors have both person_id and movie_id.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem lies in this line of code:

```
JOIN movies ON movies.id  = directors.person_id
```

instead of linking "directors.person_id" you should use "directors.movie_id". Just a simple error :)

The fact that you JOINED movies as well was just unnecessary, but the result shouldn't change.
The next issue is that your result has 3389 rows, and gets approved by check50, while on the pset page it says that the result must have 3392 rows.

I wrote this that has 3392 rows.

```
SELECT name FROM people WHERE id IN (SELECT person_id FROM directors WHERE MOVIE_ID IN (SELECT movie_id FROM ratings WHERE rating >= 9.0));
```

Both get approved, I don't know why...